# Make a method available to deriving class, but not beyond that

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, methods, scope

Is there a way to make a method in a base class (Custom, so editable) public to classes that inherit it, but not beyond that?

I want the given method to be "private" within all classes that 'contain' it, but to not be accessible from other classes.

**A little context:**

I have three very similar classes, and am creating a base class with some properties and methods that the three classes share. Some of these properties and methods are private and should be, but I can't set them as private in the base class or they can't be accessed within the three.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `protected` keyword

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) access modifier.

Answer (score 3):

You want the `protected` keyword:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) access modifier probably is what you're looking for. A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.